# Cocoa screen capturing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do you capture an NSImage of the screen in Cocoa? I need to know the fastest way, because I'm trying to make a screencasting app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [OpenGLCaptureToMovie](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/) sample. I'd add that you should use [Quartz Display Services' refresh-notification APIs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001070-CH202-341696) instead of a timer.

Note that the OpenGL example doesn't produce NSImage objects. There's no point in doing so, since you can't put those into a movie. Well, I guess you could assign an NSImage at a specified frame time, but I don't know how well that would work with compression.

Speaking of compression, use the Animation codec at maximum quality for your recording. This provides decent enough compression to not overwhelm the disk, and certainly won't overwhelm the processors. You can then offer conversion options, such as H.264, H.264 for iPhone, and H.264 for iPod. You should also allow the user to keep the original file; some sites, such as Vimeo, will accept it and allow visitors to download it.

Comment: Old answer is old. Today, I'd use the CGWindowList API to do the capture, and switch to OpenGL only if CGWindowList proves too slow.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for this update to old answer. I wanted to do an open source screen record thing, is there any new elbaboration yo ucan add? :)

Comment: @Noitidart: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/

Comment: Thanks @Peter! So with that method i am basically taking multiple screenshots every like 25ms? I couldn't find hte OpenGL CaptureToMovie example, do you know where that is?

Comment: @Noitidart: I think it was removed for being an old and grody way to do it. And yeah, movie speed is a bit too fast to take screenshots using CGWindowList. For screen recording on 10.7 and later, you want AVCaptureScreenInput: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureScreenInput_Class/ (CGWindowList is still the ideal for capturing single static images.)

Comment: (Also, I don't think there's a way to use the Animation codec in AVFoundation. You'd record directly to H.264 unless you can find a reason to use one of the other supported codecs.)

Comment: Thanks Peter! Will try that out and let you know how it goes! :)